# Why don't my Google Maps Markers load?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm new to JavaScript and the Google Maps API v3. I'm trying the Developer's Guide sample code in an ASP.Net page. The map displays as expected, but the marker doesn't load. I'd appreciate it if someone could spot my mistake:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-41.2954168187213,174.767133718655 )
    function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
    }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: "Hello World!"
    });
    // The following set map made no difference.
    //The constructor above should have been enough?
    //marker.setMap(map);
    //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<body  onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the Marker code inside the initialize function. Otherwise the marker doesn't see the created map.

Comment: To extend this answer- You're making the Marker, then when the doc loads, making the Map. This means the marker has nothing to "latch on to"- The map variable is null. You need to first load the map, and THEN latch markers on to it. If you want, you can create a Marker Queue, and run through it as the page is running, adding markers from it to the map if the map is ready.

Comment: Thanks. It seems so obvious now.